# move-group not working because "Cylinder dimensions must be non-negative."

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am simulation a UR3e robot in gazebo together with rviz moveit. I get the following error upon launching:

```
[ WARN] [1591114719.159732243]: Link 'Load' is not known to URDF. Cannot disable collisons.
[ INFO] [1591114719.161109044]: Loading robot model 'Rokubi'...
[ WARN] [1591114719.161164691]: Skipping virtual joint 'fixed_base' because its child frame 'base_link' does not match the URDF frame 'world'
[ INFO] [1591114719.161183782]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Cylinder dimensions must be non-negative.
[ INFO] [1591114719.513265950]: rviz version 1.13.12
[ INFO] [1591114719.513324036]: compiled against Qt version 5.9.5
[ INFO] [1591114719.513338308]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1591114719.535686766]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
[move_group-9] process has died [pid 4230, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group roku/roku/IMU:=roku/IMU /follow_joint_trajectory:=/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory __name:=move_group __log:=/home/dimitri/.ros/log/b6eaa3ce-a4ec-11ea-9134-c0b6f9fd3f63/move_group-9.log].
log file: /home/dimitri/.ros/log/b6eaa3ce-a4ec-11ea-9134-c0b6f9fd3f63/move_group-9*.log
```

But the mentioned log file does not exist.
I checked the urdf files in the ur_e_description folder but I did not find any negative dimensions.

My launch file looks like this (the importan part comes after "if launching with manipulator"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Gazebo parameters -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false" doc="Start gazebo in paused mode."/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true" doc="Starts gazebo gui."/>
  <!-- Model parameters -->
  <arg name="sensor_id"     default="SensONE"/>
  <arg name="payload"       default="none"/>
  <arg name="manipulator"   default="false"/>

  <!-- imu & ft plugin don't use the same topic name convention, here it's unified -->
  <remap from="roku/roku/IMU" to="roku/IMU"/>

  <!-- need to spawn the model in an empty world -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  </include>


  **<!-- if launching with manipulator -->**
  <group if="$(arg manipulator)">

    <!-- UR3e.launch -->
    <include file="$(find ur_e_gazebo)/launch/controller_utils.launch"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find ur_e_gazebo)/controller/arm_controller_ur3e.yaml" command="load"/>
    <node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    <node name="ros_control_controller_manager" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" respawn="false" output="screen" args="load joint_group_position_controller" />

    <!-- launch planner -->
    <include file="$(find ur3_e_moveit_config)/launch/ur3_e_moveit_planning_execution.launch">
      <arg name="sim" value="true"/>
      <arg name="limited" value="true"/>
    </include>

    <!-- overwrite semantic description to work with rokubi -->
    <param name="robot_description_semantic" textfile="$(find rokubimini_description)/moveit/roku_ur3e.srdf" />

    <!-- launch Rviz with MoveIt -->
    <include file="$(find ur3_e_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
      <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    </include>
  </group>

  <!-- load xacro to robot_description -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find rokubimini_description)/urdf/model.xacro'
    sensor_id:='$(arg sensor_id)'
    payload:='$(arg payload)'
    manipulator:='$(arg manipulator)'"/>

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
    <!-- this is where the z offset comes from, when removed, MoveIt crashes due to collision with the gound plane -->
  <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot -z 0.1" respawn="false" output="screen" />

</launch>
```

Anybody an Idea where this error comes from? Or where I should look for these wrong dimensions?
I already tried cleaning the catkin workspace an rebuilding it. Als I tried deleting the workspace and reinstalling the packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353876/move-group-not-working-because-%22cylinder-dimensions-must-be-non-negative.%22/) by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok i found the error. The height of a cylinder in the collision model somehow was negative. Weirdly this did not throw an error until yesterday. Maybe ROS or Moveit got an update that changed something there?

---

Originally posted by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) with karma: 54 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-03**:
*Which* collision model contained a negative height? Your own or one of the models you include?

**Comment by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on 2020-06-03**:
One of my own. I just changed the sign and it works now.